# Clearing an ObservableCollection after populating it with entries

Tags: c#

I have the following code to populate a Treeview with drives (RootDrive) and directories. 
But how do I clear the directories collection after each loop? What happens now is that *all* directories in *all* drives are added to each drive. 
When I use directories.Clear() in the Finally statement there are no directories added to each drive.

```
static public ObservableCollection<GetDrive> RootDrive = new ObservableCollection<GetDrive>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    ObservableCollection<GetDirectory>directories = new ObservableCollection<GetDirectory>();

    foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(di.Name))
            {
                directories.Add(new GetDirectory(s));
            }               
        }

        catch (IOException)  //drive is not ready, e.g. DVD drive
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            RootDrive.Add(new GetDrive(di.Name, directories));
            directories.Clear();
        }
    }
}

}
```

}

Comment: What is the point of clearing a collection you just populated?!

Comment: Point is populating the collection with new items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply put, use a local variable instead. And you are misusing the finally directive.

```
static public ObservableCollection<GetDrive> RootDrive = new ObservableCollection<GetDrive>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        ObservableCollection<GetDirectory>directories = new ObservableCollection<GetDirectory>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(di.Name))
            {
                directories.Add(new GetDirectory(s));
            }               
        }
        catch (IOException)  //drive is not ready, e.g. DVD drive
        {
           // Handle it?
        }    
        RootDrive.Add(new GetDrive(di.Name, directories));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, should have seen this myself

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to change the code bit and add clear method after the first for loop. like below...

```
static public ObservableCollection<GetDrive> RootDrive = new ObservableCollection<GetDrive>();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    foreach (DriveInfo di in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        try
        {
            directories.Clear();
            foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(di.Name))
            {
                directories.Add(new GetDirectory(s));
            }               
        }

        catch (IOException)  //drive is not ready, e.g. DVD drive
        {

        }

        finally
        {
            RootDrive.Add(new GetDrive(di.Name, directories));

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Wow, thats fast.. but it did not work. Now only the directories of the last drive are added to each drive.

Comment: Can you send me the complete source I can help you in this matter surely if I have complete source